# Jquery mouseenter triggers on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want an event to trigger when I hover my mouse over an object.
When I try to use jquery's mouseuner or mouseover the event triggers once when the page loads, and does not trigger when I hover over the image or imagebox

My code is below. I really don't understand what's happening.
Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            var img = '';
            var offset_const = 0.03;

            var timer = '';

            $(document).ready(function(){

            function init(obj, image, psize){
                var height = obj.height();
                //obj.height(1000);
                var imageId = 'vtourImg';

                img = $('<img id="'+ imageId +'">');
                img.attr('src', image);
                img.attr('height', height);
                obj.append(img);

                //$(obj).mouseenter(function(e){setInterval(function(e){scroller(e);}, 1000);});
            }

            function scroller(e){
                //setTimeout(scroller(e), 10000);
                var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
                var midX = $(this).width() / 2;

                var current_offsetX = img.offset().left;
                var offsetX_add = offset_const * -1 * (x - midX);
                var offsetX = 0;

                offsetX = current_offsetX + offsetX_add;

                img.offset({left: offsetX });
            }

                init($('#vtour'), 'virtualtour4.jpg', 0.00);
                img.mouseenter(alert('test'));
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="vtour" style="width:500px;height:500px;border:3px black solid;overflow:hidden;"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Page-load optimization tip: put your scripts in the `<body>` tag just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a function into the `mouseenter` method:

```
img.mouseenter(function(){alert('test')});
```

Now the anonymous function will be executed as soon as you enter.  As you had it, you executed `alert('test')` on page load, but never passed any function to the event handler.

Comment: Was just about to answer the same exact thing. jsfiddle showing this answer: http://jsfiddle.net/BV6H4/